# Convert General "Family" Tree to Binary Tree (Not BST)

Tags: java, string, linked-list, tree, binary-tree

I am currently considering different ways to accomplish the task of converting a family-type general tree (where each parent can have as many children as necessary) to a binary tree such that the left child of the parent node is inserted to the left of the parent and the right child of the parent node is inserted to the right of the (oldest) child node and so on.

This is the structure of how the binary tree must look like when converted from the general tree: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-generic-treen-array-tree-to-binary-tree/

I fed in my data by creating class object GTNode for the General Tree to add the nodes with the following values being passed:

```
//name = value1; numChildren = value2
GTNode gtn = new GTNode (String name, int numChildren);
```

No issues with constructor, this is purely to illustrated the main focus of the node is indeed the name of the family member. Thus this really can't be converted and sorted by a Binary Search Tree and is not the point of the resulting program I'm trying to create.

I was able to create methods to traverse the tree just fine, but it really doesn't help in the conversion process to the CONVERTED binary tree.

Therefore I created an additional section of code to create a linked list of the data. The reason why I did this was to establish pointers along the list which would point to the correct parent to add children to. Siblings would then be added to the right of the oldest sibling based on pointers based on where we were along real-time adding of nodes in the tree. By this time you can imagine I have two pointers going in my linked list traversal and three pointers along the tree nodes.

I can't seem to make good progress on an algorithm to create this binary tree from the data. here's a little sample code mostly pseudo code to show you basically how I'm adding nodes to the converted-style binary tree based on general tree data.

```
p=q=first; //initialize to first node f the linked list of family data

//ex. [Tom, 2] [Marc,1] [Ron,0] [Billy, 0] where Marc and Ron are Tom's children, and Billy is Marc's child)
z=root; 

//I already established x, y = root earlier and moved pointer .next in order to add children nodes to the siblings

//here we establish x and y pointers for the tree and add our root node and first child node, which will always be to the left. 
//I left it out of the while loop, because I was running into problems with null pointers. 
{


while (p.next!=null && q.next!=null)
{
   for (i = n; i>0; i--) //int n = node.numChildren; was declared earlier and then decreased 
   // n-=1 to accommodate the first child being added to left of parent node; 
   {
   //add nodes left or right to parent node: still trying to figure out the appropriate condition 
   //statements to determine addLeft or addRight from node
   }
   //here we change the pointer of the GENERAL tree parent node based on the linked list
    // add new to binary tree to the right of the last child i.e. 
    y = new BTNode(p.value,p.numChildren);
    y = x.right;
    x = y.parent; 
    x = y; //move pointer along
    q = q.next; //q moves from Tom to Marc. 
    n = q.numChildren;
    //go to beginning of while loop and as you can see, if n>0 it iterates based on the number of children
    // if n=0 exits loop and creates a new node to the right
     }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is an acceptable track to go down in terms of operability. Optimization I'm not as focused on because this is a difficult task... but could be taken into account.

Looking for pseudocode or java code shippers that would help in establishing an algorithm along these lines, or error in my logic. Again, not looking for an argument against doing a conversion like this because I want to see what it would look like as is.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question would benefit greatly from a drawing of what the data structure might look like, even if it is only a simple one. I'm having trouble picturing it, and phrases like "the left child of the parent node is inserted to the left of the parent" are confusing, at least to me. If a parent has more than two children, some children will be at lower levels in the tree? I don't understand your distinction between a binary tree and a BST. To me they are the same. It is called a binary tree because each node can have two child nodes. There are other tree structures, of course.

Comment: The following is the guidelines of conversion by hand: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-generic-treen-array-tree-to-binary-tree/ . The nodes are not sortable by integer because they are Strings referring to names. The names have relationships between each other, so they can't be sorted alphabetically - in that case I believe BST would be fine. But this is a relationship tree not an ordered tree. I already have the drawing based off of the general knowledge of how to convert by writing on a piece of paper. Now I need to figure out how to translate that to actual code

Comment: This is the difference between BST and binary tree: https://www.upgrad.com/blog/binary-tree-vs-binary-search-tree/

Comment: Hmm, I believe that's wrong, as it implies a BST cannot contain two values that are equal. Of course, that's a requirement one *might* want to impose, but the ones I coded in college allowed duplicates and had a less-than-or-equal vs. greater-than relation between the left and right sub nodes. But I get your point. One is just a tree structure, but a BST is *ordered*. But isn't your tree ordered? You said the oldest sibling goes on the left and the younger on the right. That's an ordering.

Comment: The way the tree would be ordered is by two conditions: a) the way the data is ordered in terms of parents and b) how many children.    I clarified above. There are two values in each node to take into consideration, not just one. It is ordered by the relationship between parent and child not only by age - did the data I posted make sense in the pseudocode in OP? This is more about expressing a theoretical concept in code rather than sorting family based on age, # of children, *only*